# appending <tr> dynamically as per the database output using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

I am trying to attach multiple  rows dynamically ( as per the results fetched from the database) to the existing table.

my html code

```
<table width="100%" border="1" class="queriedResponders">
                            <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th><strong>Select</strong></th>
                                <th><strong>Responder Name</strong></th>
                                <th><strong>Responder Company</strong></th>
                                <th><strong>Responder Number</strong></th>
                                <th><strong>City</strong></th>
                                <th><strong>Distance(Km)</strong></th>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

my jQuery code

```
$.ajax({
                data: data,
                url: url,
                type: 'POST',
                datatype: 'JSON',
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    var result = $.parseJSON(response);
                    var count = result.length;
                    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                        var $row = $("<tr><td><input type='radio' name='assignRadio'></td><td>" + result[i].name + "</td><td> Murgency Global Network</td><td>" + result[i].number + "</td><td>" + result[i].city + "</td><td> 0.5 Km</td></tr>");
                        $('table.queriedResponder > tr:last').append($row);
                    }
                    console.log($row);
                }
            });
        });
```

Please note :- I am getting the desired result as I have console logged the output which is a JSON object like 1 pasted below

```
[{"name":"mihir panchal","company":"","number":"00919664804737","city":""}]
```

Please guide me as to where am I making the mistake

Answer (score 2):

2 things:

1. You are not referencing the correct element. Your table has a class of `queriedResponders`, and you are targeting `queriedResponder`
2. You should be append to the tbody instead of the tr

Both of those things combined results in this:

```
$('table.queriedResponders tbody:last').append($row);
```

I've simplified the response to get a working example:

```js
var result = [{
  "name": "mihir panchal",
  "company": "",
  "number": "00919664804737",
  "city": ""
}];

var count = result.length;
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  var $row = $("<tr><td><input type='radio' name='assignRadio'></td><td>" + result[i].name + "</td><td> Murgency Global Network</td><td>" + result[i].number + "</td><td>" + result[i].city + "</td><td> 0.5 Km</td></tr>");
  $('table.queriedResponders tbody:last').append($row);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="100%" border="1" class="queriedResponders">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th><strong>Select</strong></th>
      <th><strong>Responder Name</strong></th>
      <th><strong>Responder Company</strong></th>
      <th><strong>Responder Number</strong></th>
      <th><strong>City</strong></th>
      <th><strong>Distance(Km)</strong></th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: hey I found the answer .. changed the selector from $('table.queriedResponders > tr:last') to $('table.queriedResponders > tbody:last') and it worked..

Comment: Haha, great timing! I just made the same update. I'm glad you caught it

Answer (score 0):

You are appending the new row to the last tr while you want to append it in `<tbody>`
so you should replace it with

```
$('table.queriedResponders > tbody:last-child').append($row);
```

or if you want to use your last `<tr>` you may use `.after()` instead of `.append()` to add the new row after your last row

```
$('table.queriedResponders tr:last').after($row);
```

**Solution1:** [Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/u42hb3yv/)

**Solution2:** [Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rsodu8mc/)